# lock bash script to prevent parallel running from within the script itself?

Tags: shell-script, concurrency, flock

I am aware of using `flock` and `solo` (not sure the difference though) when running from a cron job. However, is it possible to prevent parallel running from within the script itself?

Comment: use lockfile with `lckdo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ipor Sircer said, `lckdo` is probably the right choice.

Within the `bash` script maybe like this:
$BASHPID is the running scripts PID. You could save it to a file and check for existence (or even better check if that containing PID is still active).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PIDFILE="/foo/bar/script.pid"

# script running?
[[ -s $PIDFILE ]] && exit

# no, create pidfile
echo $BASHPID > $PIDFILE


# .. do some stuff

# delete pidfile
rm $PIDFILE
```

Comment: You would probably need to check the contents of the file too, to make sure the process is actually running. Common case when you logout while a process is running.